# getDate() slice() confusion

Tags: javascript, date, slice

Hello I'm trying to remove the first number of a date. Let's say today was 15 May, how would I

1. remove the first integer and keep 5 only
2. be sure that that single digits (ex 5 June) stays the same? I tried the slice property but it doesn't seem to work.

My fiddlesticks: https://jsfiddle.net/DimitriXd4/gp2eaaot

```
var now = new Date();
var getTheDate = now.getDate().slice(-1);
console.log(getTheDate );
```

In theory `slice(-1)` should cut the last number and return it even if it a single number/word, right?

Comment: now.getDate() returns 5 as it is

Comment: see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Comment: `getDate` returns a **number**, which does not have a `slice` method. You could either convert it to a string, or you could just use `% 10`.

Comment: @DavidJones I mean yes today we have 5 may so it return 5, but if we had 16 may i would like to keep the second digit only(6).

Comment: Use `now.toDateString().slice(-1);` see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gp2eaaot/2/

Comment: @Bergi ohh, now i get it, will tinker it further. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var now = new Date();
    var getTheDate = (now.getDate() + "").slice(-1);
    console.log(getTheDate );
```

The empty string concatenated with the result, converts it to a string, then allowing slice to work

Comment: Thank you very much, can you explain what the empty string does in this situation?

Comment: included explanation

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer you found more useful to you. :)

Answer (score 3):

`slice()` is String method, and getDate() doesn't return a String, thats why you can't call `getDate().slice(-1);`
You have to convert it to String, and then use slice.
e.g.

```
var getTheDate = now.getDate().toString().slice(-1);
```

But it doesn't change the original date variable, it will give you only sliced string. If you want to update the date you should do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `slice()`. As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) suggested, it is easier to operate on the number by taking the remainder modulo 10.

```
var dateRightDigit = (new Date().getDate() % 10) + "";
console.log(dateRightDigit);  // "0" or "1" or ... or "9"
```

This simpler approach of using modulo is preferable because when you slice a string, there are more concerns to consider. You have to know how long the string is, how the `start` and `end` arguments work, and what negative numbers mean.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input and thanks for editing my horrible format ^.^

Answer (score -1):

The other answers do not seem to account for single digit numbers so here is a function that checks the date before slicing.

```
var sliceDate = function(dateObject){
   var dateToSlice = dateObject.getDate();
   //if the date is a two digit number
   if (dateToSlice > 9) { //NOTE we should not have to worry about the  date being negative
      dateToSlice = dateToSlice.toString().slice(-1); //change to string then slice
   }
   return Number(slicedDate); //convert back to number and return
};
console.log(sliceDate(new Date())); //will print out 5 if May 5th or 6 if May 16th
```

**Edit**

Here is a more concise version:

```
var getTheDate = new Date().getDate();
var slicedDate = (getTheDate > 9) ? Number(getTheDate.toString().slice(-1)) : getTheDate;
```

Comment: Code is too complicated

Comment: @Nayuki Edited with a more concise example that is hopefully helpful?